# ¿Como convertir un valor General o Alfanumérico en Hexadecimal en Excel?

Tags: vba, macros, binario

Es solo una consulta de proceso.
Dentro de un Macro en VBA y completando valores con formulas de excel, he tratado de hacer una conversión directa de alfanumérico a Hexadecimal, ejemplo;

Text >>> Santiago69
Hex >>> 53616E746961676F3639

Mi pregunta es, dentro de este proceso en VBA o a través de formula en Excel se puede integrar?
o es únicamente pasando el texto a binario y posterior a Hexadecimal?

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente, hay que convertir cada carácter a su código de control ASCII y ese número convertirlo a hexadecimal. (no hace falta llegar a convertir a binario)
Sería:  "A" -- codigo Ascii de ("A") - convertir CodigoAscii a hexadecimal
Por lo que hay que recorrer la cadena o text para poder obtener todo el valor. Por tanto, con fórmulas, no digo que no se pueda, pero teóricamente al no poder crear iteraciones con fórmulas...lo veo negro

Lo mejor es hacerlo por VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Const HEX_STRING_PREFIX As String = "0x"
Const VBA_HEX_PREFIX As String = "&h"

' Lás lineas de arriba, irían en la parte posterior del código, para que sean globales

Public Function HexEncode(AsciiText As String, Optional HexPrefix As String = HEX_STRING_PREFIX) As String

  If AsciiText = vbNullString Then

    HexEncode = AsciiText

  Else

    Dim asciiChars() As Byte
    asciiChars = StrConv(AsciiText, vbFromUnicode)

    ReDim hexChars(LBound(asciiChars) To UBound(asciiChars)) As String

    Dim char As Long
    For char = LBound(asciiChars) To UBound(asciiChars)
      hexChars(char) = Right$("00" & Hex$(asciiChars(char)), 2)
    Next char

    HexEncode = HexPrefix & Join(hexChars, "")
  End If

End Function
```

Cualquier duda, lo vemos